# How to verify the assertion returned by navigator.id.get in node.js?

Tags: node.js, post, npm, bigint, browserid

Alright, so I'm trying to verify an assertion returned by browserID to sign in a user. To do so I was trying to use the `browserid-verifier` package. However I wasn't able to install it. There's an error in the `node-bigint` package as shown below:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/browserid-verifier
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/browserid-verifier
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jwcrypto/0.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jwcrypto/0.1.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.0.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/browserify/1.8.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vows/0.5.13
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.2.6
npm http GET https://github.com/benadida/node-bigint/tarball/2ac68
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.0.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/browserify/1.8.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/vows/0.5.13
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.2.6
npm http 200 https://github.com/benadida/node-bigint/tarball/2ac68

> bigint@0.3.7 install /home/aaditmshah/struggleforlife/node_modules/browserid-verifier/node_modules/jwcrypto/node_modules/bigint
> node-waf configure build

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr 
'configure' finished successfully (0.022s)
Waf: Entering directory `/home/aaditmshah/struggleforlife/node_modules/browserid-verifier/node_modules/jwcrypto/node_modules/bigint/build'
[1/2] cxx: bigint.cc -> build/Release/bigint_1.o
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/detective
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deputy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nub
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commondir
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
../bigint.cc:9:17: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/aaditmshah/struggleforlife/node_modules/browserid-verifier/node_modules/jwcrypto/node_modules/bigint/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx bigint.cc -> bigint_1.o}
npm ERR! error installing bigint@0.3.7
npm ERR! error installing jwcrypto@0.1.1
npm ERR! error installing browserid-verifier@0.0.4

npm ERR! bigint@0.3.7 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bigint@0.3.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bigint package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bigint
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.0.0-17-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "browserid-verifier"
npm ERR! cwd /home/aaditmshah/struggleforlife
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.14
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message bigint@0.3.7 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! message `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! errno {}
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/aaditmshah/struggleforlife/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

So instead I tried writing my own code to verify the assertion. This is what I came up with:

```
var mongoLife = "mongodb://nodejitsu:02a0f2d1cacb5259588ddfdfad59cf49@staff.mongohq.com:10088/nodejitsudb449201704656";

var querystring = require("querystring");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var express = require("express");
var https = require("https");
var nowjs = require("now");

mongoose.connect(mongoLife);
var app = express.createServer();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(app);

everyone.now.login = function (assertion) {
    var client = this.now;

    var postData = querystring.stringify({
        audience: "http://life.nodejitsu.com/",
        assertion: assertion
    });

    var options = {
        host: "browserid.org",
        path: "/verify",
        method: "POST",
        port: 80,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Length": postData.length
        }
    };

    var request = https.request(options, function (response) {
        response.setEncoding("utf8");
        response.on("data", function (responseText) {
            var user = JSON.parse(responseText);
            client.loggedIn(user.status === "okay" ? user.email : null);
        });
    });

    request.write(postData);
    request.end();
};

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

app.listen(8080);
```

However when a user tries to sign in I get the following error:

```
[Error: 139723080664896:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:683:]
Error: 139723080664896:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:683:

    at CleartextStream._puller (tls.js:501:24)
    at CleartextStream._pull (tls.js:432:19)
    at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:727:20)
    at EncryptedStream.write (tls.js:130:13)
    at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:367:14)
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1107:15)
    at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (http.js:1210:27)
    at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at Array.0 (tls.js:792:22)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Any help will be appreciated. All I'm trying to do is create an HTTP POST request to `https://browserid.org/`, pass the assertion and the audience, and check the return status. I would like to know exactly where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. In my options I had set the port to 80. Since I'm using HTTPS the port should have been 443. So I removed the port to allow it to select a default port. Also since it receives data in chunks I just collected all the chunks into a single message and parsed the entire message when it was received. Yay, I'm so proud of myself.

```
everyone.now.login = function (assertion) {
    var client = this.now;

    var postData = querystring.stringify({
        audience: "http://life.nodejitsu.com/",
        assertion: assertion
    });

    var options = {
        host: "browserid.org",
        path: "/verify",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Length": postData.length
        }
    };

    var request = https.request(options, function (response) {
        var responseText = "";

        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
            responseText += chunk;
        });

        response.on("end", function () {
            var user = JSON.parse(responseText);
            client.loggedIn(user.status === "okay" ? user.email : null);
        });
    });

    request.write(postData);
    request.end();
};
```